# Problemas al enviar Objeto dentro de otro

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola chicos estoy teniendo problemas para mandar un JSON con multiple informacion nose como hacerlo, les esplico con codigo para mejor entendimiento .

```
  $id=$_SESSION["id"];   
 //estoy estrayendo todos los id de los usuarios que son mis amigos en total tengo 8 
      $verifyFriends=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE 
             de='{$_SESSION["id"]}'");

         while($array1=mysqli_fetch_array($verifyFriends)){
          //con un while estoy intentando sacar los ids en total son 8   
           //en la tabla  multichat_messages hay un campo llamado id_users
           //contiene el id de los usuarios que han enviado mensajes    
           $select=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM
           multichat_messages
           WHERE id_user='$id' OR id_user='{$array1["para"]}' ORDER BY date DESC");

   //sacando informacion de la tabla multichat_messages        
      $array=mysqli_fetch_array($select);   
 //esta es la manera que mas me gusta de enviar JSONS y es la que mas domino            
 echo json_encode(array(
                        'minesf'=>$array1["para"],//ok este es el campo que nescito extraer todos los id pero solo me arroja un id y deberian ser 8 en total
                        'photo'=> $array["photo"],
                        'message'=> $array["message"],
                        'name' => $array["name"],
                        'date'=> $array["date"],
                        'lastn' => $array["lastname"],
                        'newm'=>$new));

                header("Content-Type: application/json");
            }
```

alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal tambien intente con este codigo pero no se muy bien como enviar un array dentro de otro `'minesf'=>{$array1["para"]}` cuaquier ayuda seria genial gracias chicos!

Comment: Andy tu pregunta no se entiende bien: ¿cuál es el problema en sí? ¿qué resultado estás teniendo? ¿qué resultado esperas obtener? Si puedes pon un ejemplo de lo que pasa ahora y de lo que esperas como resultado. Una cosa sí es cierta,  **el `header` debe ir antes del echo** y conviene que le pongas el **charset utf-8**, para que no te sorprenda con caracteres extraños: `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` ... El código es mejorable, por ejemplo, yo nunca mandaría a ejecutar un `SELECT` dentro de un bucle, muy malo para la BD. Se pueden obtener los datos en 1 solo.

Comment: gracias por responder @A.Cedano te explico en la consulta nesecito que me arroje 8 ids por que son 8 amigos que tengo por lo tanto deberia arrojar 8 ids entotal pero solo me arroja 1 id, osea aqui `'minesf'=>$array1["para"],` los otros objetos que manda estan bien este es el unico que estoy teniendo problemas para el resultado no se si me doy a entender

Comment: el resultado que estoy esperando es mas o menos asi `minesf: 'id1',id2,id3,id4 etc..`

Comment: No del todo Andy. Si te explicas mejor [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173745/edit), podrás tener incluso una respuesta que te ayude no sólo a resolver el problema, sino a optimizar y dar seguridad al código. Dependiendo cómo estén organizadas tus tablas, puedes obtener los 8 ids en una sola consulta, en vez de consultar la BD 8 veces, o `n` veces como estás haciendo ahora. También tu código es vulnerable a Inyección SQL. Si quieres una buena respuesta debes ser claro en la exposición del problema, o conformarte quizá con una respuesta mediocre.

Comment: vale entiendo mira la variable `$array1["para"]` contiene 8 ids entonces esos 8 ids los nececito enviar via json , osea  esa sola variable contiene 8 ids es mas o menos como tu hacer un objeto asi `objeto={ "nombre":"perdo","edad",18}` en este caso con el while deberia la variable 
 `$array1["para"]` obtener los 8 ids

Comment: Andy tú puedes obtener los datos en una sola consulta y luego convertir los resultados de esa consulta en un JSON. Pero es preciso que edites la pregunta, explicando cómo están organizadas tus tablas, para poder ayudarte.